# Integral involving exponential function?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was working on a problem and reduced it to evaluating
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\exp\left\{\frac{bxe^{-bx}}{2(1-e^{-bx})}\right\}\,dx~~a,b>0$$
your suggestion? Thanks.

By considering $u=e^{-bx}$ and $c=a/b$, I have
$$\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1}y^{c-1}exp\{-\frac{y}{2(1-y)}\ln(y)\}\,dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{c+k-1}}{(1-y)^k}(\ln y)^k\,dy$$

Comment: @Arbuja: I doubt this is homework.  It is a difficult enough integral that I think the OP is OK simply asking if anyone around here has ideas.

Comment: Do you need to actually evaluate, or just get some asymptotic?

Comment: $y^{c-1}\exp (v \log y)=y^{c-1+v}$ with $v=-y/2(1-y).$  Still looks obscure though.I doubt that we can express the anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions.